# Getting error 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' ON andoid app

Tags: java, android

Here is my layout

**ProfileDisplay.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Profiledisplay">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profilimg"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/progileicon"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="mailid@mail.com"
    android:id="@+id/mailid"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="name"
    android:id="@+id/name1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bloggerorweiter"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Blogger or Writer"
     />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/City"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="City"
        />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/state"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="State"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/Country"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Country"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:background="#97145C"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header">
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

**ProfileDisplay.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
public class Profiledisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
NavigationView navigationView;
ImageView imgview;
FirebaseAuth mauth;
String currentuserID;
private DatabaseReference userref1;
TextView name,country,mailid,city,state,blog_writer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imgview=findViewById(R.id.profilimg);
    name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
    country=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Country);
    mailid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mailid);
    city=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.City);
    state=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.state);
    mauth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    blog_writer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bloggerorweiter);
    currentuserID=mauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    userref1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
   try{
    userref1.child(currentuserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("username")){
                        String fullname1 = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                        **name.setText("123456");**
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("urlimage")){
                    String imageurl=dataSnapshot.child("urlimage").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageurl).into(imgview);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Profiledisplay.this, "username or profile not exist", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                String Email="gaakash149@gmail.com";
                mailid.setText(Email);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });}
   catch(Exception e){
   }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiledisplay);
    navigationView=findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.home:
                    Toast.makeText(Profiledisplay.this, "CLicked Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.Profile:
                    Toast.makeText(Profiledisplay.this, "CLicked profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Profiledisplay.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.Post:
                    Toast.makeText(Profiledisplay.this, "CLicked Post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),forgotpass.class));
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

**error**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 25982
>       ***java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.myapplication.Profiledisplay$1.onDataChange(Profiledisplay.java:51)***
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7055)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:523)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:836)

I got this error every time when I am trying to do SetText() method.

**build.gradel file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: Here is the even i am trying with enter string value in name.settext("123456") still gives the error]

Comment: I am able to fetch dtat from firebase but can't able to put data in the Textview .This causes app crashes.

Comment: check if `fullname1` gets some value or its null

Comment: I have checked it full name has value "Akash" but it still getting error

Comment: This this is works successfully in another activity before but write now its giving me error

Comment: It's not clear what check you've performed to assure that `fullname1` isn't null, but I would expect the code to test that it's not null -- particularly if `setText` will throw an exception if it is null.

Data and the dynamics of responding to changes are more likely the culprit than any code dependency.

Comment: Sir jmarks I have checked fullname1 has value in the form of string  but its not able to settext.  When I used it in name.setText(fullname) it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setContentView before calling findViewbyID.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiledisplay); // move setContentView here
    imgview=findViewById(R.id.profilimg);
    name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
 ....
```

Your problem is that the view was null when you were trying to finditbyid.

**Update**

In other words:

1. setContentView before trying to get reference to the view:

   Focus here `setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiledisplay);`
2. Make sure that there is a TextView named `name1` in `activity_profiledisplay.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but its stops the app crash but not able to put text on Textview.

Comment: I have added build.gradle file if there is any dependency error please tell me.

Comment: Did you made the change? If yes, please share your new code and new error logs

Comment: If there is error in dependency, your code will not even compile - you can't run app with wrong dependency

Comment: I had tried to give simple String value like this "name.setText("123456") but still its not getting the same error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' "

Comment: Share complete new code. What you are talking is impossible.

Comment: mayank1513 I have edited in the code in name.settext("123456") but still gets error

Comment: Thanks mayank1513 I have sucessfully get rid of error your idea is right. I have accidently used setcontentview twice in my code

Answer (score 0):

**Your Java Activity XML file not match with same Activity.**

*setContentView(R.layout.*********);//here your matching activity.*

*Like when u create new activity , MainActivity its xml file name is    activity_main...* 
*Use Binding Easy To Understand ...*